# Nested function in c?

Tags: c, function, nested

The aim was to implement a c function, that takes two unsingned int n and m and computes the non-negative result m^n. It also said to ignore possible overlows.

So here is the solution given out by the lecturer:

```
unsigned int power(unsigned int m, unsigned n) {
int power(int x, int y) {
  int result = 1;
  while(m > 0) {
  result *= n;
  --m;
  }
 return result;
}
```

While i understand the algorithm itself, i fail to get why he chose to use a nested function. And also why there is a curly bracket missing.

I would have simply written something like this:

```
unsigned int power(unsigned int m, unsigned n) {
  int result = 1;
  while(m > 0) {
  result *= n;
  --m;
  }
 return result;
}
```

Could somebody please explain, why he chose the nested one and why that's better?

Comment: why you think the first one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `int` version was a copy/paste left over error: there are no references to either `x` or `y`.

```
unsigned int power(unsigned int m, unsigned n) {
int power(int x, int y) {                        /* copy/paste left overs */
  int result = 1;
  while(m > 0) {
  result *= n;
  --m;
  }
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested functions are not supported in standard C and there is a extension in GNU C which supports it but is not a standard.

The code what you have written is good and there is a mistake in the code your lecturer has given you.

To know about nested functions you can look here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a mistake in the solution the lecturer gave you. Your code seems correct.

Comment: @WeatherVane, the hand out the correct solution after the deadline

Answer (score 1):

C language does not support defining functions inside functions. You can however declare a function inside a function.

gcc has an extension that supports nested functions. See [this](//gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).